# CakePHP 1.3: getting authError message on successful login

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I'm trying to implement a login feature where a user can use his username or email address. I've worked out the login with both, but when the user logs in successfully with his email address, the authError still flashes (user is logged in). I've put a comment "HERE" down in the login action, and I'm not sure what happens after that with the redirect.

Here are the relevant bits of my code:

App Controoler:

```
public $components = array(
    'Auth' => array(
        'authorize' => 'controller',
        'loginRedirect' => array(
            'controller' => 'users',
            'action' => 'welcome_page'
        ),
        'loginError' => 'Invalid user name/password',
        'authError' => 'You don\'t have permission'
    ),

    'Session',
);
```

User Controller:

```
public function beforeFilter() {

    parent::beforeFilter();

    $this->Auth->allow('add');
}

public function login() {       

    // At this point, the Auth Component is unable to log in user, so check with email.
    if (!empty($this->data) &&
        !empty($this->Auth->data['User']['username']) &&
        !empty($this->Auth->data['User']['password'])) {        

        // Look for user with email address using the entered username
        $user = $this->User->find('first', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'User.email' => $this->Auth->data['User']['username'],
                'User.password' => $this->Auth->data['User']['password']
            ),
            'recursive' => -1
        ));

        // Check if a matching user is found and that if login was succesfull
        if (!empty($user) && $this->Auth->login($user)) {       

            if ($this->Auth->autoRedirect) {
                // NOTE: user trying to log in with email reaches HERE
                $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());   // this is the default authentication redirect defined in App Controller
            }


        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash($this->Auth->loginError, $this->Auth->flashElement, array(), 'auth');
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: The AuthMessage is stored inside the session and will be removed from the session after showing it using `echo $this->Session->flash();`. Is it possible you didn't show that message on the login page when the login was unsuccessful, thus the message of the unsuccesful login wasn't cleared?

Answer (score 0):

I edited your original post to delete the messages from the session variables.

```
<?php

$this->Session->delete('Message.flash');
$this->Session->delete('Message.auth');

?>
```

Hope this helps!

-Andrew